# How to create a background color transition that lasts 2 seconds for a div when it is added to the DOM?

Tags: html, css

So I have list of items in my page and a WebSocket connection to backend that receives new items and inserts them into my list. I want newly-inserted items to display with background color transition that lasts a second or two.
How do I go about creating a CSS style that transitions background color but does so for only a second or two when it is first rendered?

Answer (score 0):

CSS by itself can not trigger an animation for newly created items, this you have to do from JS when you add the element - or using a MutationObserver to listen to such an event.

One method could be to define the animation in CSS and then add the corresponding class using JS when the element is created. Or just define a transition for the background-color in CSS, but change the CSS background-color property from JS.

A third option, depending on if you use a framework or what kind of framework you use, may be to just do the animation using JS.

Answer (score -1):

[keyframe](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)
use a class css with an animation property that lasts until 2. the keyframe will allow you to transition from the backgroun